# Java: when calling repaint() on a JPanel, the components in the same JFrame redraw themselves in the top left corner

Tags: java, swing, jframe, repaint

I have a Graph class that extends JPanel.  It gets repainted on mouseMoved.  When this happens, basically any other component that was added to a layout (whether it be the same JPanel or a seperate JFrame) will get pained on the top left corner.  I have a screen shot to go with the following code.  If you look closely in the top left, there is a small textarea that is appearing.  This will happen with any component.

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

    private JTextArea txtPoints = new JTextArea(20, 40);

    GUI() {
        setSize(800, 1000);
        setLayout(new MigLayout());
        add(new Graph(), "wrap");
        add(txtPoints);
        setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: Further tips:  1) Don't extend `JFrame`, just use an instance of one.  2) Don't call `setSize(..)`, instead call `pack()` **after** the layouts are set and the components added. 3) GUIs should be constructed on the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.  It is not possible to tell from that incomplete code, whether that rule is obeyed.  Just thought I'd put that idea out there as it is a common mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of broken paint chain.

Without further evidence, you've overridden some `paintXxx` method and failed to call `super.paintXxx` meaning that what ever was previously painted to the `Graphics` context still remains...

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details